# EtherDelta confusion

Tags: wallet, exchanges

I recently bought EtherDoge from EtherDelta and the amount of tokens I received in my wallet shows as something like 10000010000000. The EtherDoge website shows the total supply of EDOGE as 100 billion so how does that work? Obviously I can see that doesn't make sense but don't understand why my wallet shows a number higher than 100 billion. Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm completely new to this so wanted to find out. Thanks

Comment: I'm having alot of issues using ED as well.  It's very difficult to use and right now is totally unresponsive.